# React setState sets to default

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a simple login form page in React. The `<form>` has 2 inputs (email and password), an error message, and a submit button.
The submit button can be set to the Loading state during the authentication request.

So I have the following component:

```js
function LoginForm() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ loading: false, error: "", x: 1 }); // x value only for visualising...
  const auth = useAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const login = async ({ email, password }) => {
    try {
      if (!email || !password) {
        return { errors: "Invalid fields" };
      }

      const { errors } = await auth.authenticate(email, password);

      if (!errors) {
        return {};
      }
      console.log("LoginButton", "Error login. Not Redirecting", errors);
      return {
        errors: "Por favor verifique seu email e/ou senha e tente novamente.",
      };
    } catch (error) {
      return { errors: "Unexpected error. Please, try again later." };
    }
  };

  const inputs = [
    {
      name: "email",
    },
    {
      name: "password",
      type: "password",
    },
  ];

  const handleSubmit = (values) => {
    setState({ ...state, loading: true, error: "", x: 2 }); // First call
    login(values).then(({ errors: error }) => {
      if (!error) navigate("/profile");
      const newState = { loading: false, error: "Error while login", x: 3 }; // Second call
      setState(newState);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state); // Only for debugin
  });

  return (
        <Form
          inputs={inputs}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
          <ErrorMessage text={state.error} />
          <div>
            <Submit loading={state.loading}>Entrar</Submit>
            <Link
              to="/forgot-password"
            >
              Esqueceu sua senha?
            </Link>
          </div>
        </Form>
  );
}
```

The `<Form/>` component only gets the inputs array and creates the list of inputs...

The login function was called, and it set the state successfully on the first `setState` call (x: 2), but on the second call, the state was reset to the default value (x: 1).
Why did the second `setState` reset the default value? How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by `default value` ? What was the value of state when second time it runs ?

Comment: The value set on `useState` -> `{loading: false, error: "", x: 1}`

Comment: Try `setState(prev => ({...prev, newState}));`

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved... But I don't Understand how...

```js
function LoginForm() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ loading: false, error: "", x: 1 });
  const auth = useAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const inputs = [
    {
      name: "email",
    },
    {
      name: "password",
      type: "password",
    },
  ];

  const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
    const { email, password } = values;
    setState({ ...state, loading: true, error: "", x: 2 });

    auth.authenticate(email, password).then(({ errors }) => {
      if (!errors) navigate("/profile");
      const newState = { loading: false, error: errors, x: 3 };
      setState(newState);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state);
  });

  return (
        <Form
          
          inputs={inputs}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
          <ErrorMessage text={state.error} />
          <div>
            <Submit loading={state.loading}>Entrar</Submit>
            <Link
              css={`
                color: white;
              `}
              to="/forgot-password"
            >
              Esqueceu sua senha?
            </Link>
          </div>
        </Form>
  );
}

export default LoginForm;
```

This worked...